# Scaling a Game Maker app for mobile-device screens

Tags: html, mobile, scaling, game-maker

I'm having a difficult time getting an HTML5 app I designed in Game Maker to scale for display on mobile-device screens. I've tried using this little bit of code, to set the width and height of a the main game room, in a setup object, before switching to that room:

```
room_set_width(rm_playspace,browser_width);

But that seems be doing absolutely nothing.
```

Have you successfully designed software for mobile devices with Game Maker? How did you get your software to scale for proper viewing on mobile devices with differently sized screens?

Answer (score 1):

> room_set_width( ind, w );
>
> **Description**
>
> With this function you can change (or set) the width of any room in your game **except the current one**.

so you need to go to another room, and then resize the first room and go back into it.

another option that you can try - just restart the room immediately after resizing, like

```
room_set_width(room, 640)
room_set_height(room, 480)
window_set_size(640, 480) // also you can use window_set_rectangle
room_restart()
```

(room should not be a persistent)

Comment: I'm already setting the width and height of the play room in the setup room, which initializes at the start of the game and then switches to the play room; so, trying to re-size the current room isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set `view_port_xxx` and `view_size_xxx` for proper sizes. You can use `window_get_width()` and `display_get_width()` etc. for that - refer to manual for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just resize the surface and before, the view.